# Block Kick or set Limit to Kick Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

hello I don't want the mods to do kick action in my server i see discord.js doesnt add guildKickAdd like guildMemberAdd 
so how can i block kick or set limit kick ?

this is ban block when someone do ban action bot taking roles and gives him punished.

````
client.on("guildBanAdd", async function(guild, user) {
  const entry = await guild
    .fetchAuditLogs({ type: "MEMBER_BAN_ADD" })
    .then(audit => audit.entries.first());
  const yetkili = await guild.members.get(entry.executor.id);
  setTimeout(async () => {
    let logs = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: "MEMBER_BAN_ADD" });
    if (logs.entries.first().executor.bot) return;

    guild.members
      .get(logs.entries.first().executor.id)
      .removeRoles(guild.members.get(logs.entries.first().executor.id).roles); ///TÜM ROLLERİNİ ALIR
    setTimeout(() => {
      guild.members
        .get(logs.entries.first().executor.id)
        .addRole("633026228537917460"); /// VERİLECEK CEZALI ROL İD
    }, 3000);
    const sChannel = guild.channels.find(c => c.id === "641032067840344064");
    const cıks = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(
        `<@${yetkili.id}> ${user} adlı Kişiye Sağ tık ban Atıldığı için Banlayan Kişinin Yetkileri Alındı`
      )
      .setFooter("Created by Tokuchi");
    sChannel.send(cıks);
    guild.owner.send(
      `Tokuchi Affetmez † Guard | ** <@${yetkili.id}> İsimili Yetkili <@${user.id}>** Adlı Kişiyi Banladı Ve Yetkilerini Aldım.`
    );
  }, 2000);
});```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `guildMemberRemove` event:

```js
// When a member left. Maybe he left himself, but maybe he was kicked.
client.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
    // Get the last kick case of the server
    const entry = await guild
    .fetchAuditLogs({ type: "MEMBER_KICK" })
    .then(audit => audit.entries.first());
    // if there's not any kick case in this server
    if(!entry) return;
    // if the target was not the member who left
    if(entry.target.id !== member.id) return;

    // Else, you know the member was kicked, and you have the entry so you can do what you want
});
```

This is the best way to know if someone was kicked.

Comment: yeah i did it like this but when someone leaves, he take the roles of the person who invited him

Comment: [link](https://hasteb.in/lafuhala.js) this is i used command like i said when i used this command when someone leaves, bot takes the roles of the person who invited him